# What is the meaning of highlighted part in the paragraph given down below ? I tried dictionary but it didn't help me the way I wanted it to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of **“now woven into the tapestry of time”** and **"heart-strung"** in the picture I have posted here. I tried look through the dictionary but couldn't make the sense out of it.

[image]

Comment: Even the full OED doesn't list ***heartstrung***, so it's no surprise you're struggling with that one. Extrapolating from ***heartstrings*** (usually plural, metaphorically ***tugged / pulled at*** by touching / poignant circumstances), I'd guess your cited writer means something like "spirits who are closely associated with emotions" (the metaphorical heart). But I'd say it's just terrible "mock-Victorian" writing - I can't help it if you find the subject matter interesting, but this is certainly no text from which to learn modern English!

Comment: (*now woven into the tapestry of time* is just a fancy metaphorical way of saying ***now long past***.)

Comment: "Woven" is the past tense of "weave". Have you looked up "weave" and "tapestry", and is there still a question? "Heart-strung" seems to be a reference to "heart-strings", which can be found in dictionaries.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Obviously it's a *reference* to "heartstrings". But I can't really see how to assign a reliable ***meaning*** to the (adjectival) past tense form of that "whimsically verbified" noun. Easiest way for me to deal with it is to simply assume the writer is an idiot who doesn't understand how to use English properly!

Comment: @FFRM I did a search at Google Books, and found a number of instances of "heart-strung" in poems. But I agree there's not much meaning there... It's love and only love!

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: I know ***hamstrung*** (incapacitated by having one's hamstrings cut), and ***cross-strung*** (way of arranging the strings in a piano), plus I just found ***bowstrung*** (strangled with a bowstring, a former Turkish method of execution! :) But that doesn't really give any help when it comes to "parsing" ***heartstrung***. Frankly I think it's got no currency and never did have - most of the relatively few instances I found in Google Books look to me like "failed malapropisms" for ***heartfelt***.